# how to install php_zip

Tags: php, php-5.2

As per php manual I have already enable php_zip.dll in the php.ini file and also check php_zip.dll in ext folder of php installation folders. It appears there. But While using code for zip it shows errors as below:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\projectname\bulkdownload.php on line 9
```

Following is the code of bulk download.php

```
<?php

function zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path)
{
$zip = new ZipArchive();
    //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE )!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$archive_file_name>\n");
    }
    //add each files of $file_name array to archive
    foreach($file_names as $files)
    {
        $zip->addFile($file_path.$files,$files);
    }
    $zip->close();
    //then send the headers to foce download the zip file
    header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$archive_file_name"); 
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    readfile("$archive_file_name"); 
    exit;
}

$file_array = $_GET['voice'];
$file_names = explode(';', $file_array);
$archive_file_name = "voicefile.zip";
$file_path = "d:/temp_file/voice/";


zipFilesAndDownload($file_names,$archive_file_name,$file_path);

?>
```

Comment: What's your PHP version? The Zip class has been built-in for a while.

Comment: I have install PHP 5.2.0 and inetpub as web server and windows 2008 as server. php_zip.dll was already installed or built-in php 5.2.0. but still it showing error

Answer (score 1):

Run phpinfo().
Above the  "zlib" heading, see if there is a "zip" heading. If not then the zip module has not been installed correctly. If so check that it is "enabled".

Comment: phpinfo() doesn't show zip heading but zlib information is given. Isn't zlib is for zip??

Comment: No, zlib is not the same as (pk)zip.